# Logic to calculate the number of records for change in a column value

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, logical-operators

In the following query,I tried to calculate

The number of distinct employees who changed the FTE status from Active to Inactive or vice versa

between

Report Month dates '2015-01-01' and '2015-06-30'

and

date of termination >='2015-01-01' or date of termination is null

and

region being NAM.

I'm getting 770 records but it should be 606.I'm not sure if the logic in my query is correct.Thanks in Advance!

```
  SELECT A.[First Name]
    ,A.[Last Name]
FROM (
    (
        SELECT [First Name]
            ,[Last Name]
            ,[Report Month]
            ,[Region]
            ,[Date of FTE Termination]
        FROM dbo.Data
        WHERE (
                [Report Month] BETWEEN '2015-01-01'
                    AND '2015-06-30'
                AND (
                    [FTE Status] = 'Inactive'
                    OR [FTE Status] = 'Active'
                    )
                AND (
                    [Date of FTE Termination] >= '2015-01-01'
                    OR [Date of FTE Termination] IS NULL
                    )
                AND [Region] = 'NAM'
                )
        ) A INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [First Name]
            ,[Last Name]
            ,[Report Month]
            ,[Bill To Code]
            ,[Region]
            ,[Date of FTE Termination]
        FROM dbo.Data
        WHERE (
                [Report Month] BETWEEN '2015-01-01'
                    AND '2015-06-30'
                AND (
                    [FTE Status] = 'Active'
                    OR [FTE Status] = 'Inactive'
                    )
                AND (
                    [Date of FTE Termination] >= '2015-01-01'
                    OR [Date of FTE Termination] IS NULL
                    )
                AND [Region] = 'NAM'
                )
        ) B ON A.[First Name] = B.[First Name]
        AND A.[Last Name] = B.[Last Name]
    )
GROUP BY A.[First Name]
    ,A.[Last Name]
ORDER BY A.[First Name] ASC
```

Comment: First you need to tell us why you feel that you should get 606 records. If you are getting more records than you think you should get, then check the individual table for the joining key,  you probably have duplicates there.

Comment: Its been tested in Excel and found to have 606 records,They both are the same table.It's an inline query with different condition.How do i exclude the duplicates within this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JOIN doesn't force the joined rows to have opposite FTE Status.

You need to change it to this:

```
ON A.[First Name] = B.[First Name]
AND A.[Last Name] = B.[Last Name]
AND (
  (A.[FTE Status] = 'Active' AND B.[FTE Status] = 'Inactive')
OR (A.[FTE Status] = 'Inactive' AND B.[FTE Status] = 'Active')
)
```

Then by adding those conditions to the JOIN, you can remove them from the WHERE clauses, although they aren't really hurting anything by being there.

Comment: Thank you Tab,I'll look into it!

Comment: Your logic seems correct but I'm only getting 95 records..Not sure why there is a huge difference

Comment: You have duplicates in the table for First_name and last_name combination. In excel it behaves differently , there we do not join with the same table.  You need to join the tables on unique key from both the tables.  Also you are using the same inline select twice, better use CTE

Comment: Can you give an example of a row that is not being returned by the query with my change, that you would expect to be returned?

Comment: Tab,Its a list of names,not sure how i can share the data set,But I'll try it on my own for a while and get back to you if i cant crack it,Hopefully I'm close to the right answer.Thank you for you're intelligent logic as always!.:)